# Theano import error: "AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'gof'"

Tags: theano

I've been having a problem importing Theano with Anaconda.  Everything I've tried from various stack overflow questions has failed.  Below is the entire error when I import Theano "from theano import shared, theano as tt"

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Theano but that has not worked.  I also tried to install m2w64-toolchain from a previous stack overflow thread.  However, I could not install it and got a PackagesNotFoundError.

I'm using a Macbook pro (Mojave) and have the latest Conda and Anaconda installed.

> Exact error:
>   ---------- You can find the C code in this temporary file: /var/folders/jw/3xbk25v11px1f9l229j_x_5r0000gn/T/theano_compilation_error_a0t0msed
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/anaconda3/envs/env_full/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/lazylinker_c.py
>   in 
>        80                     version,
>   ---> 81                     actual_version, force_compile, _need_reload))
>        82 except ImportError:
>
> ImportError: Version check of the existing lazylinker compiled file.
>   Looking for version 0.211, but found None. Extra debug information:
>   force_compile=False, _need_reload=True
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/anaconda3/envs/env_full/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/lazylinker_c.py
>   in 
>       104                         version,
>   --> 105                         actual_version, force_compile, _need_reload))
>       106         except ImportError:
>
> ImportError: Version check of the existing lazylinker compiled file.
>   Looking for version 0.211, but found None. Extra debug information:
>   force_compile=False, _need_reload=True
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/anaconda3/envs/env_full/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/vm.py
>   in 
>       673         raise theano.gof.cmodule.MissingGXX('lazylinker will not be imported if theano.config.cxx is not set.')
>   --> 674     from . import lazylinker_c
>       675
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/env_full/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/lazylinker_c.py
>   in 
>       139             cmodule.GCC_compiler.compile_str(dirname, code, location=loc,
>   --> 140                                              preargs=args)
>       141             # Save version into the **init**.py file.
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/env_full/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py
>   in compile_str(module_name, src_code, location, include_dirs,
>   lib_dirs, libs, preargs, py_module, hide_symbols)    2395 
>   -> 2396         if py_module:    2397             # touch the **init** file
>
> Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): In file included from
>   /Users/tingli/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-18.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.7.3-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:1:.
>   In file included from
>   /Users/tingli/anaconda3/envs/env_full/include/python3.7m/Python.h:25:.
>   /Users/tingli/anaconda3/envs/env_full/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdio.h:108:15:
>   fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found. #include_next .
>   ^~~~~~~~~. 1 error generated..
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 from theano import shared, theano as tt
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/env_full/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/**init**.py
>   in 
>       108     object2, utils)
>       109 
>   --> 110 from theano.compile import (
>       111     SymbolicInput, In,
>       112     SymbolicOutput, Out,
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/env_full/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/compile/**init**.py
>   in 
>        10 from theano.compile.function_module import *
>        11 
>   ---> 12 from theano.compile.mode import *
>        13 
>        14 from theano.compile.io import *
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/env_full/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/compile/mode.py
>   in 
>         9 import theano
>        10 from theano import gof
>   ---> 11 import theano.gof.vm
>        12 from theano import config
>        13 from six import string_types
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/env_full/lib/python3.7/site-packages/theano/gof/vm.py
>   in 
>       681 except ImportError:
>       682     pass
>   --> 683 except (OSError, theano.gof.cmodule.MissingGXX) as e:
>       684     # OSError happens when g++ is not installed.  In that case, we
>       685     # already changed the default linker to something else then CVM.
>
> **AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'gof'**